# mysql-workbench column row with DEFAULT value of 0 not NULL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a database with the column: `clicks int(11) DEFAULT NULL`.

If i give this column a default value of `NULL` the increment of:

`UPDATE table SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE id=:id");`

is not working, but when i change it to 0, manually, everything works.

How can i give the column the default value of **0**.

By the way if i type 0 as default value in mysql workbench, 
the database still displays NULL, no matter what.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try below query.

```
UPDATE table SET clicks = ifnull(clicks,0) + 1 WHERE id=:id");
```

Also, you can try altering your table.

```
  ALTER TABLE table
  CHANGE COLUMN clicks clicks INT DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: nope it says warning: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Comment: then maybe try to change your table schema using alter query.                     
    alter table table change column clicks clicks int default 0;

Comment: ok now it works ! I recreated the table with default 0 and it works now, thanks a lot.